# How do you generate A1-style references in Scala?

Tags: scala

How do you generate A1-style references in Scala (e.g., A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2, etc.).

I can zip together two lists to generate a single vector of tuples:

```
"ABCDEFG".zip("1234567")
```

generates:

```
Vector((A,1), (B,2), (C,3), (D,4), (E,5), (F,6), (G,7), (H,8), (I,9))
```

However, attempting to flatten this into a single list of results in the following error.

```
error: No implicit view available from (Char, Char) => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].
```

Aside from resolving the error, it does not really generate the list of A1-style references desired. How do you generate a list of A1-style references in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `flatMap` calls in reverse order of how we want the numbering to occur solves the prolbem.

```
"123456789" flatMap { row => 
    "ABCDEFGHI" flatMap { col => 
        Seq(s"${col}${row}")
    }
}
```

A more concise answer to the problem uses a for-comprehension:

```
for {
    row <- "123456789"
    col <- "ABCDEFGHI"
} yield s"${col}${row}"
```

which yields a vector of reference strings:

```
Vector(A1, B1, C1, ..., G9, H9, I9)
```

Answer (score 3):

zip() is OK, just map properly

```
scala> "ABCDEFG".zip("1234567").map{case (c,r) => c + r.toString}
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(A1, B2, C3, D4, E5, F6, G7)
```